# Passing gridview values(data) to textbox fields

Tags: c#, gridview, textbox, controls

For my view,
In the page:

```
1) I have a gridview with the select hyperlink in it. The gridview data is from the SQLDataSource. 

2) And, I also have a few textboxes (abt 5) - not in the gridview.
```

What I would like to do is to use the select `hyperlink` to select the `row` that i want to edit. And when i click `select`, the `data` in the `row` should come out to their respective `textboxes`.
How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Grid views have inline record editing support, you can enable this functionality by setting the `AutoGenerateEditButton` property to true. You must specify the name of a stored procedure or SQL query in the `UpdateCommand` property, this is used to update data in the underlying data base.

From MSDN:

```
      <asp:gridview id="CustomersGridView" 
        datasourceid="CustomersSqlDataSource" 
        autogeneratecolumns="true"
        autogeneratedeletebutton="true"
        autogenerateeditbutton="true"
        datakeynames="CustomerID"  
        runat="server">
      </asp:gridview>

      <asp:sqldatasource id="CustomersSqlDataSource"  
        selectcommand="Select [CustomerID], [CompanyName], [Address], [City], [PostalCode], [Country] From [Customers]"
        updatecommand="Update Customers SET CompanyName=@CompanyName, Address=@Address, City=@City, PostalCode=@PostalCode, Country=@Country WHERE (CustomerID = @CustomerID)"
        deletecommand="Delete from Customers where CustomerID = @CustomerID"
        connectionstring="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthWindConnectionString%>"
        runat="server">
      </asp:sqldatasource>
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogenerateeditbutton.aspx) for the full example code.

Answer (score 0):

Wireup `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event:

ASPX:

```
<asp:GridView id="gvTest"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvTest_SelectedIndexChanged"
 ..........></asp:GridView>

<asp:TextBox id="text1" runat="server"/>
```

Code:

```
 protected void gvTest_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    //get currently selected row
    var r =gvTest.Rows[gvTest.SelectedIndex];

    //THIS WAY YOU CAN GET TEXT FROM ALL COLUMNS
    text1.Text = r.Cells[r.Cells.Count - 1].Text;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void gvofertas_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        gvofertas.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        switch (e.CommandName)
        {

            case "ELIMINAR":
                {
                    //lblSolEliminar.Text = "Usuario: " + Convert.ToString(gvCorreos.DataKeys[gvCorreos.SelectedIndex].Values["etspcpusrn"]);
                    mpeEliminar.Show();
                    break;
                }
            case "EDITAR":
                {
                    Limpiar();
                    Session["NROOFERTAACTUALIZA"] = Convert.ToString(gvofertas.DataKeys[gvofertas.SelectedIndex].Values["efophcodi"]).Trim();
                    txtDescripcion.Text = Convert.ToString(gvofertas.DataKeys[gvofertas.SelectedIndex].Values["efophdesc"]).Trim();
                    StartDate.Text= Convert.ToDateTime(gvofertas.DataKeys[gvofertas.SelectedIndex].Values["efophfini"]).ToShortDateString();
                    EndDate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(gvofertas.DataKeys[gvofertas.SelectedIndex].Values["efophffin"]).ToShortDateString();
                    txtRango1Localidades1Agregar.Text = Convert.ToString(gvofertas.DataKeys[gvofertas.SelectedIndex].Values["efophloci"]).Trim();
                    txtRango2Localidades1Agregar.Text = Convert.ToString(gvofertas.DataKeys[gvofertas.SelectedIndex].Values["efophlocf"]).Trim();
                    this.mpeAgregar.Show();
                    BtnGuardar2.Text = "Actualizar";
                    txtDescripcion.Focus();
                    break;
                }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        ucMsje.RegistrarMensajeCliente("dvMsjeError", F.m_strImagenError, ex.Message);
    }
```

Comment: Please keep the source code in english and explain your answer. Just posting a bunch of code ain't an appropriate way to answer.